# Git Bash wit Visual Studio Code: how to set permanent PATH

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I'm using VSCode with git bash and minGW. Every time I restart VSCode the PATH is reset to default. I add my path to mingw with export PATH=$PATH:/c/mingw/bin
How can be permanent changed? I created .bashrc in my code folder but it doesn't works
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "path" in the windows control panel. you can then "edit the system environment variables". You can edit it in to the system path.

You will need to restart VSCode after you change it, then it will be there every time..

Note that in the future this may cause problems if you have a separate version of something using mingw dlls.