# Bash Commands Do Not execute on my Python `venv` Virtual Environmnent on VSCode

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, python-venv

Am Implementing a Flask Webapp that requires a virtual Environment to manage dependencies. I have created a virtual environment called `venv`. I am Using a Bash Terminal on Visual Studio Code.
When I spawn a new bash Terminal at first without logging in the, the Bash commands work perfectly

```
Admin@blahblah MINGW64 ~/techblog/venv/Scripts (main)
$ ls
activate      deactivate.bat    pasteurize.exe*  python.exe* 
activate.bat  flask.exe*        pip.exe*         pythonw.exe*
Activate.ps1  futurize.exe*     pip3.11.exe*
alembic.exe*  mako-render.exe*  pip3.exe*
```

Then I activate it using the command;

```
Admin@blahblah MINGW64 ~/techblog/venv/Scripts (main)
$ cd ../..

Admin@blahblah MINGW64 ~/techblog (main)
$ source venv/Scripts/activate
```

The moment I am within the environment the Bash commands do not work.

```
Admin@blahblah MINGW64 ~/techblog
$ clear
bash: clear: command not found
(venv) 
Admin@blahblah MINGW64 ~/techblog
$ ls
bash: ls: command not found
(venv)
```

Also when I exit the same environment I find that the Subsequent bash commands to the Terminal Itself do Not work.

This is the Bash `venv/Scripts/activate` script contents;

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}" ] ; then
        PATH="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
        hash -r 2> /dev/null
    fi

    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}" ] ; then
        PS1="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    unset VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT
    if [ ! "${1:-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="C:\path\to\my\web\app\techblog\venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "${PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="${PYTHONHOME:-}"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    PS1="(venv) ${PS1:-}"
    export PS1
    VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT="(venv) "
    export VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT
fi

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2> /dev/null
fi
```

what am I missing or where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly tried setting git bash as the default integrated terminal and it solved the problem. Visual Studio Code on Windows uses PowerShell by default as the integrated terminal.

I used [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal) to guide me in setting up bash as the default integrated terminal on my VS Code.
Note that I had also set the path of my git bash executable to my [PATH environment variable for my windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289480/git-bash-wit-visual-studio-code-how-to-set-permanent-path) before I Tried setting bash as the default Integrated Terminal.

Comment: @JialeDu I have to wait for 2 days to accept my answer. will definitely do that. Thanks!